# Can I reverse the run order of a Flutter Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to write a simple layout using the `Wrap` widget. I'm wondering if there is any way to get "overflowing" elements to be placed in the first run rather than the last. For example, lets say I have a horizontal `Wrap` with 7 elements and I can fit four elements in each run. Instead of having the last three elements end up in a run (row) at the end, I would like the only the first three to end up in a run (row) at the beginning.

Can I achieve this without resorting to a different layout widget?

Also, is there any way to force a new run to start after a certain element in a wrap? If I for example always wanted the first element on its own row?

Comment: What about you create list of widget and then reverse the order of list of widget before putting them inside wrap.

Comment: I believe that would still create a row of four elements followed by a row of three elements instead of the reverse

Answer (score 4):

There is an property called textDirection, wich odd enough doesn´t only control the text but the widgets.

So you have an order of items like

```
A, B, C, D|

E, F      |
```

you add

```
Wrap(
   ...
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
   ...)
```

The items become

```
D, C, B, A|

      F, E|
```

There is a great explanation of the possibilities of the wrap widget in this [article][1] in Medium.

Edit:

Wrap starts to "wrap" from the same direction, so a layout like

```
A, B      |
C, D, E, F|
```

is indeed, impossible with only wrap.

However. You might be able to do it if you instead use Rows and Columns layout. Additional logic it's required but the result should be possible.Since there is no code of how you implement the layout i will try my best to explain it.

```
List<Widget> widgetList = [WidgetA,WidgetB,WidgetC,WidgetD,WidgetE,WidgetF]; //The widget list A,B,C,D,E,F...  Each widget SHOULD be wrapped in Expanded(), and have a fixed height to avoid infinity height
List<Widget> reversedList = List.from(widgetList.reversed); //F,E,D,C,B,A
//We need to split this in sub list of 4 items each, I will use Spacers()  on the last sublist if it's not 4, to keep a nice layout
List<List> subLists=[];
for (var i = 0; i < reversedList.length; i +=4) {
    bool isLastSublist = i+4 > reversedList.length ;
    List subListToAdd = reversedList.sublist(i, isLastSublist ? reversedList.length : i + 4);
    //When the lengthis less than 4 we add spacers to maintain the layout spacing
    if(subListToAdd.length>4){
        for(var o = subListToAdd.length;o<=4;o++){
            sublistToAdd.add(Spacer());
        }
    }
    subLists.add(subListToAdd); 

}

//in other part of your code
//...

Column(
...
verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
children:List<Widget>.generate(subLists.length,(int index) => Row(children:subLists[index]))
...
)
```

I'm not in my flutter pc right now so i can't test it, but the concept is there, the code can be optimized
[1]: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-wrap-widget-e1ee0b005b16

Comment: Thanks but it's not really what I'm after. What I would like is something which in your example would leave `A, B` on the first row and `C, D, E, F` on the second.